# Storing file input in an array and outputting to another file C++ (File I/O)

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I am trying to read file input into an array, line by line, and then output it to another file line by line. My thinking was to read each word and assign it to an array index and then immediately output the word stored in that index to the output file. I'm not very knowledgeable of using Visual Studio's debugger or any debugging for that matter. I just try to compile without errors but when using this code, I get an error saying:

"Exception thrown at 0x0119A1C6 in EndOfFileDemo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.

If there is a handle for this exception, the program may be safely continued"

and it gives me the options to: Break, Continue, or Ignore.

I am hoping someone can look at my code and find the logical error I am not seeing or if I am using a bad syntax error.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::cout;

int main( )
{
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;

fin.open("Programming Assignment 3 Data.txt");
if (fin.fail( ))
{
    cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
    exit(1);
}

fout.open("newOut.txt");
if (fout.fail( ))
{
    cout << "Output file opening failed.\n";
    exit(1);
}


char next;                // a variable to store each word
fin >> next;

while(fin >> next)         // I've read on several other questions that
    {                     // this is better than: while (! fin.eof())
    string myArray[8];
    myArray[0] = next;
    fout << next << " ";
    int i = 1;
    while(next!='\n')             //read and write until end of line
    {
        fin >> myArray[i];
        fout << myArray[i] << " ";
        i++;
        fin >> next;
    }
    fout << endl;  //output an end of line to begin next output on new line.

    fin >> next;         
}

fin.close();
fout.close();

system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

The .txt file for input reads:

```
h Vito 123
d Michael 234 Heart
n Sonny 456 6
a Luca 567 Business
r Tom 678 Talking Y
j Anthony 789 Maintenance N
d Nicos 891 Bone
```

It is a roster for hospital employees and each word will later be stored in it's own member variable within different model classes.
For example the second entry would be stored in an object of the class "Doctor" with the following member variables:
 role
 name
 number
 specialty

And to index multiple instances of Doctors, I will later create an array for objects of the class "Doctor" to be stored.

But I wanted to first get the handle of how to properly input and store individual words (to later be assigned to variables) and output the data to a file.

Comment: Reading into unbounds-checked arrays where the number of iterations comes from outside the program is dangerous. Either validate that `i` does not overflow the array, or use a data structure that performs bounds-checking automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately the instructor is not allowing me to use any data structures.

Comment: why dont you just use the getline() function to get the whole line of the file ? Btw next is a char ?

Comment: @user3553067 `std::string` and built-in arrays are data structures. If he wants you to use arrays in this way, ask your instructor why he wants to teach you to write insecure programs.

Comment: @user3553067 you are filling an array of size 8, but your code don't have any check to not exceed this limit. Also, I suppose you should read the entire file into the array instead of reading/writing at each byte (considering the title of the question).

Comment: Because later I'm going to be need to assign each word to a different member variable of a class. But I wanted to make sure I could read individual words into an array correctly first before moving on to that part. I don't know how to read a whole line and then break it apart into separate words.